# Why is a json_encoded object ending up as an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am passing some data to javascript using PHP in a project I am working on it. In my PHP I have:

```
<?php
        $allprojects = $pages->find('projects')->children();
        $transfer = array();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($allprojects as $p) {
            $transfer[] = array(
                'i' => $i,
                'title' => $p->title()->value,
                'url' => $p->url(),
                'thumb' => thumb($p->children()->first()->images()->first(), array('width'=>170))
            );
            $i++;
        }


    ?>
    <script>
    var projects = <?php print json_encode($transfer); ?>
    </script>
```

If I then try to use this variable `projects` it is an array. I.e.:

```
projects instanceof Array == true
```

I am a bit confused as to why this is the case. Can anyone illuminate the situation?

Comment: You are defining an array and you are asking why it is an array?

Comment: I think he means because associative arrays are more like objects--though many are unware that JavaScript arrays can also have non-numeric keys.

Comment: @BrettZamir Even more fun is that it isn't an assoc array ;-)

Comment: I think I'm confused here. I defined an array, yes, but then I attempted to encode it as a JSON object. My understanding is that json_encode() converts the array to a JSON string. Or is that not what I have done?

Comment: You got an array of objects. Isn't what you expected ?

Comment: I've got to stop shooting answers from the hip :)

Comment: @PeeHaa with all due respect, that kind of response is supremely annoying, arrogant, and condescending. At least if you are going to attempt an insult, accompany it with some piece of information to help resolve my confusion.

Comment: What is the problem? You said you thought you were confused and I acknowledged it. I as well linked to the official documentation where your question is answered on the frontpage of said shared link.

Comment: Wait ! You are setting a string value on "projects" variable. How can this be an array ? I am confused too right now :P

Comment: @fraxture: With the code `$transfer[] = ...` you are incrementing an array numerically, so the outer array (`$transfer` itself) is numeric.

Comment: `projects[0] instanceof Array == false`

Comment: Thank you @Bram and @BrettZamir. I think I am starting to understand. In order to avoid this, I would need code that sets a string key for each array object? Also, where in the resulting JSON string is the outer array indicated. I get as a result: `[{"i":0,"title":"A Project","url":"http:\/\/lanningsmith.sunny.net\/projects\/a-project","thumb":"<img src=\"http:\/\/lanningsmith.sunny.net\/thumbs\/ec4c1f22b1e4d0a9660054fbed0c5613.170.0.0.0.0.100.jpg?1393045637\" width=\"170\" height=\"130\" alt=\"download1\" \/>"},...]`.  But can't quite see where the 'numeric' outer array is indicated.

Comment: `[...]` denotes an array. As already pointed out, have a look at http://json.org/. The first diagram describes the syntax of an object (`{string: value, ...}`), the second one the one of an array (`[value, ...]`). As in most programming languages, for arrays/lists the indexes don't have to be explicitly specified, since they are already encoded in the the position of the element.

Comment: That's what a JSON array looks like, it has no numeric indications. You cannot add them because that's not something javascript will accept. The real question is: what's wrong with an array?

Comment: @Bram: This doesn't really have anything to do with JavaScript at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a data interchange format for representing an object or a list of objects as a string. In your case you're using the format to interchange your list (specifically an array) `$transfer[]` from the PHP running server-side to the Javascript on the client side.

If you view the resulting HTML source in your broswer you will see that the line:

```
var projects = <?php print json_encode($transfer); ?>
```

has been rendered as, for example:

```
var projects = [{i: 1, title: "Example", url: "www.example.com", thumb: "example.jpg" }];
```

so as far as JavaScript is concerned this line is defining `projects` as an array (using `[]`) of objects (using `{}`). So you have successfully used the format to exchange the array of objects you started with from the server to the client.

If you want to get the JSON format of it into a variable on the client side again, perhaps in order to pass it back to the server somehow, you can use:

```
var projectsJSON = JSON.stringify(projects);
```